# I cannot find the Cordova debug configuration in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on a Windows 10 Home Edition os. I have installed Visual Studio Code Version 1.9.0 and added to it the Cordova Tools 1.2.6. I hava a fresh Ionic 2 blank project and I am running it with `ionic run android --device` or emulating it with `ionic emulate android`. I want to test debugging from Visual Studio Code but when I go to Debug/Add Configuration I don't see a Cordova option. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Do you see dropdown list with configrations after click on gear button? If now, I guess that launch.json is automatically generated leverage on your open files in vscode workspace. Try the following steps:

1. Remove existing launch.json
2. Close all files in workspace
3. Reload VSCode
4. Create launch.json again

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the configuration to launch.json yourself. See the extension README for examples: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova

Comment: In the documentation it says you first need to select the Cordova configuration. I tried to manually add the configuration in the launch.json but it doesn't work. Then, those debug targets, like "Run on Android device", they are also missing.

Comment: @airimiea Do you have the Cordova extension installed?

Comment: Same thing happening to me, my coworker is able to use it just fine though

Comment: @RobLourens yes, the Cordova extension is installed

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what state you're in, but the default configs will only show up if you don't already have a launch.json file, then you click the configure icon (the gear), and select Cordova from the list. If you already have a launch.json file, you have to add a cordova config manually.